# Calculate delta on filter metric

Tags: prometheus, promql

I would like to calculate the daily increase of a metric via prometheus.

Currently I am using: `delta(metric_name[1d])`.

Unfortunately there can be an instant were the value is 0, therefore it messes the daily increase if present.

Is there a way to filter some value before calculating the `delta`?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there is. You can use [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) syntax.

Comment: But how exactly do you want to filter your data? And what should happen with "windows of absence" after filtration?

Comment: Just ignore the instant, like never present

Answer (score 1):

You need to create [rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/#rule) for pre-filtering of metric_name

**prometheus.yml**

```
...
rule_files:
  - my_rules.yml
...
```

**my_rules.yml**

```
groups:
- name: my_filters
  rules:
  - record: metric_name_filtered
    expr: metric_name != 0
```

This will drop fake zero-values.

PromQL will be: `delta(metric_name_filtered[1d])`

If you need to fill-up dropped metrics, you could create one more rule:

```
  - record: metric_name_filtered_and_restored
    expr: last_over_time(metric_name_filtered[1h])
```

See also [the best practices for naming metrics created by recording rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/rules/#recording-rules)

Comment: To be fair, this can be done without rules: `delta( (metric_name !=0) [1d:])` and `delta( last_over_time( (metric_name != 0) [1h:] ) [1d:] )` respectively.